# Unable to claim free space for APFS partition Big Sur

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, big-sur, apfs

I'm trying to add additional space to my macOS Big Sur. I've tried to do complete the process by using `diskutil`. Although I did not get any errors, I was unable to claim the free space.

Subsequently, I tried running the following command to increase the size of disk1 from 70.9 GB to 99 GB.

This command gave the following error:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 99g

Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 28,073,046,016 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 98,999,996,416 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 107,163,398,144 bytes
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

How do I go about claiming the free space and expanding the size of disk1 from the current 70.9 GB to 99 GB without losing any existing data? I've seen a couple of related questions but could not really understand what exactly needs to be done in my situation.

Below are some additional details about my disk partitions.

`diskutil list` gives the following results:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *107.4 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         70.9 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +70.9 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD — Data⁩     33.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 284.7 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                626.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨TM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.3 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            VBox_GAs_6.1.26        *61.1 MB    disk2
```

Running `diskutil apfs list` gives the following results:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 1AE067F0-6E4C-4959-AC92-AED9D02A66BF
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      70926950400 B (70.9 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   49517670400 B (49.5 GB) (69.8% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       21409280000 B (21.4 GB) (30.2% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 1FDF5ADC-94EF-42CA-8023-FB21C29B598E
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       70926950400 B (70.9 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 860FEABC-E7ED-3032-BA65-EC963E1FFDC4
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD — Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         33151873024 B (33.2 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 7FF2096A-6F8A-4379-BA4D-855E70CA5046
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Preboot
    |   Capacity Consumed:         284708864 B (284.7 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 73D456FF-C1E2-4766-A7F8-D948AB61AE10
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         626225152 B (626.2 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 8A5E0ADA-669A-4D4F-9421-F7CB7EB15A0F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (TM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/TM
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1069056 B (1.1 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 9DACD09D-872D-4734-892F-755BED928C89
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (System)
        Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               Not Mounted
        Capacity Consumed:         15331196928 B (15.3 GB)
        Sealed:                    Broken
        FileVault:                 No
        |
        Snapshot:                  33CDCE03-ED90-4EE1-AA82-BBA11FE22729
        Snapshot Disk:             disk1s5s1
        Snapshot Mount Point:      /
        Snapshot Sealed:           Yes
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Additional information as requested is given below:

```
diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Size -e Offset
   Partition Offset:          20480 Bytes (40 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 209.7 MB (209715200 Bytes) (exactly 409600 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
   Partition Offset:          209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 70.9 GB (70926950400 Bytes) (exactly 138529200 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes
```

Comment: Where does Virtualbox VM come into play? Is this on non-Apple hardware? If so, then I'm afraid it's off-topic.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I'm using my Macbook air as the host machine. I've updated the question to reflect the same. Thank you.

Comment: Post the output from the commands `diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Size -e Offset` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`.

Comment: If the free space is placed before the occupied space, it will be impossible to recover it other than by cloning the system partition to an external drive, erasing the internal drive and then recloning in reverse order. Carbon Copy Cloner does this very well.

Comment: @Jean_JD: If you read the previous comments, you will learn the OP is running Big Sur in a virtual machine. So impossible may not be true. For example, the OP may be able to  increase the size of `disk 0`. When you refer to a external drive, do you mean a actual external drive or a virtual USB drive? Why not just create another virtual internal drive? Of course, if the OP has space to create an usable virtual USB or additional internal drive, then the OP would have enough space to increase the size of `disk0` instead.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Thanks for your response. I've now updated the question with the requested information. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you!